# unable to run docker image locally

Tags: docker

I have a simple node JS application as below

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello there man!'))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

So i have a docker file which is as below

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directoryy
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "sampleApp.js" ]
```

and basically i docker build and run it .

it is showing me

```
C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\oracle\wercker\nodeJS_wercker_k8 - Copy>docker run 669bf025e027
Example app listening on port 3000!
```

But when I go to local host I cant access it. The funny thing is that I tried this last week and it worked fine. Any ideas?

PS: I am a noob in dockers.

[image]

Comment: docker run -d -p 3000:3000 cheese

Answer (score 0):

You didn't map the container port 3000 to a port on localhost using the -p option.

Comment: actually i tried that too : docker run -p 3000:3000 669bf025e027 but it still didnt work.

Comment: How are you trying to access your web server?

Comment: Please attach a screen shot.

Comment: try ... docker run -P

Comment: The -P option is not what you want. To map 3000 to 3000 on local host you need -p 3000:3000. Also can you include a screen shot with your connection at attempt and the error message.

Comment: Big P and little p are different.  `-p 3000:3000` with a little "p" should work.  (`-P` with a big "P" takes no options, and asks Docker to pick an arbitrary host port for you.)